# Multi-start in OpenMDAO

Tags: optimization, openmdao, multimodal

Is there any straightforward way to use a multi-start option for solving optimization problems in OpenMDAO? I am currently using the SLSQP driver of ScipyOptimize, and would like to start the search from multiple initial points (either in a sequence of in parallel, although that is not necessary), and choose the best of the results, to increase confidence that the minimum found is a good minimum (or likely global). Is there any clever way to achieve this in OpenMDAO rather than implementing a loop "by hand"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "by hand" method (i.e. putting a for-loop around a call to `run_driver()`) is the way to do it. No fancy tricks needed.

One feature  you might find helpful is the [manual case recording at the problem level](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.16.0/features/recording/problem_recording.html). At the end of each point, you can manually record a case with ALL the variables in it. You get to name that case yourself, so you can give it a descriptive name if keeping track of which point is which would be useful to you.